# How to set camera position dynamically using three.js

Tags: three.js

I am working on a three.js parser which can parse obj and JSON file.

The problem is different objects different alignments. I need to hard code value  of camera.position.z. but this not dynamic.

How can I calculate this value dynamically? I already tried solutions from @WestLangley but it's not working. Maybe I am doing it wrong.

here is my code :

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width/ height, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = 200;

// scene
scene = new THREE.Scene();

scene.add( camera );

THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath( object_path.dir );
mtlLoader.load( object_path.mtl, function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( object_path.dir);
    objLoader.load( object_path.object, function ( object ) {

        // object.position.y = - 95;
        camera.lookAt(object.position);
        scene.add( object );

    }, onProgress, onError );
});

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( width, height);
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

Comment: @WestLangley can you please help me out here. I don;'t know what am I doing wrong..! :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a render()-Function. 
And in this function you can calculate the camera.z dynamically depending on your current state. Like:

```
      var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );

            camera.position.z =  ...
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

      render();
```